# Android alert dialog with warning message

Tags: android, android-edittext, message, alert, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog with an EditText in it and I'd like to warn the user when the entered input text is empty. So either :
- by opening a new alert dialog on the top of the current one, but without closing the current one. I tried it and I don't know how to it.
- by changing dynamically the message on my alert dialog, but again I don't how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what you want when you set the buttons for your `AlertDialog` like:

```
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Here check to see if you have an empty EditText and take appropriate measures
               }
           })
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve but I can't prevent the alert dialog from being closed. That's actually my main problem.

Comment: Ok, I found how to do it. There is no other way than creating a custom alert dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving this a shot:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "You have entered an empty string, silly!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It's just a simple popup dialog but it should suffice for your needs. You can change 'Toast.LENGTH_SHORT' to 'Toast.LENGTH_LONG' depending on how long you want the dialog to stay visible, after which it will fade away into oblivion.

Or for a more comprehensive solution:

```
public void alertMessage(string Message)
{
   Toast.makeText(this, Message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```